# Create Component with Dynamic Directives

Tags: angular

We are currently using the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` method to generate components dynamically at runtime - it's sort of a plugin system, where the user can add plugins and display screens as they wish.  The relevant code is here:

```
 this.module = moduleFactory.ngModuleFactory.create(this.injector);
 var factory = this.module.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(tab.type);
 tab.component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
```

Where `moduleFactory` is a factory to create a dynamically loaded module.  If I have a directive `SomeDirective` I would like to apply to the created component, is this possible?  The only current way I've seen is through template compilation.

Has anyone had any luck with this?  I see the parameter `projectableNodes: any[][]` in the call to createComponent, but I have no idea if this would be relevant in this case.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question. Not that this helps right now, there is 'component outlet' coming in Angular 4, hopefully this will allow this.

Comment: Yes is possible, look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284026/creating-a-angular2-component-with-ng-content-dynamically/44289996#comment121012790_44289996