# Creating an angular2 component with ng-content dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-components

I would like to set the body of `<ng-content>` while instantiating a component dynamically using `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

I see that I can get access to input & output using `ComponentRef`, but not a way to set `<ng-content>`.

Please note `<ng-content>` I'm planning on setting can contain simple text/can span dynamically created components

```typescript
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-to-project',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ComponentToProject implements AfterContentInit {

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // We will do something important with content here
    }

}


@Directive({
    selector: 'appProjectionMarker'
})
export class ProjectionMarkerDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<ComponentToProject> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentToProject);
        const componentRef: ComponentRef<ComponentToProject> = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        // Question: How to set content before the child's afterContentInit is invoked
    }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'appTestComponent',
    template: `<div appProjectionMarker></div>`
})
export class TestComponent {}
```

Comment: Use `projectableNodes` parameter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372334/why-is-projectablenodes-an-any

Comment: Can I add a dynamic component too as `projectableNodes`, so the child is available to directive's parent as `@ContentChild`?

Comment: Since it is a projectable`Node`s, I assume I can only pass `DOM` elements

Comment: No, you can inject component into it or template. But you should manipulate only nodes

Comment: I'll test that. Thanks

Comment: See from `20.00` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMjTp12VbQ8

Comment: Can u plz post this video as an answer, I'll accept it. I think it will help a lot of others

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is the `projectableNodes` parameter for the `vcRef.createComponent` method

```
createComponent<C>(componentFactory: ComponentFactory<C>, index?: number, injector?: Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][], ngModule?: NgModuleRef<any>): ComponentRef<C>;
```

You can use it to dynamically inject one component into another.

Let's say we have the following component

```typescript
@Component({
    selector: 'card',
    template: `
        <div class="card__top">
            <h2>Creating a angular2 component with ng-content dynamically</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card__body">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="card__bottom">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `
})
export class CardComponent {}
```

We want to create it dynamically and insert some controls to its `ng-content` locations. It could be done like follows:

```typescript
const bodyFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(CardBodyComponent);
const footerFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(CardFooterComponent);

let bodyRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(bodyFactory);
let footerRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(footerFactory);

const cardFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(CardComponent);

const cardRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(
    cardFactory,
    0,
    undefined,
    [
        [bodyRef.location.nativeElement],
        [footerRef.location.nativeElement]
    ]
);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GPPgRGy3djZsAsBy?preview)**

See also

- [Why is projectableNodes an any[][]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372334/why-is-projectablenodes-an-any)
- [Pawel Kozlowski - Reactive parenting with Angular 2 - NG-BE 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMjTp12VbQ8)

Comment: In this case you know beforehand that there are two ng-content, how could you know how many are there if the object is dynamically pass? I mean, if CardComponent can be any component?

Comment: I just found how to know the number of projections with `ComponentFactory.ngContentSelectors` so in this case cardFactory.ngContentSelectors.length