# Angular 4 ngComponentOutlet loads dynamic components, but route content is not being rendered

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent, router-outlet, ng-component-outlet

I'm trying to load different 'parent' components and inject route content into these different parent components by targeting `ng-content` in each parent component.  Essentially, each parent component handles the navigation and other boilerplate stuff based on device widths (small/mobile, medium/tablet, and large/desktop).

The content generated for each route in my application needs to get transcluded (injected) into the parent components.  The content for each route targets specific injection points using `ng-content`.

I'm able to swap out the parent components using `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="ResponsiveComponent;"></ng-container>`.  The problem is my route-generated content is not getting injected into the targeted `ng-content` locations in each parent component.

Here's the code for swapping out parent components.  `AppPageComponent` extends `ResponsiveComponent` which monitors device width based on media queries.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-page',
    template: `
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="ResponsivePageComponent;"></ng-container>     
    `,  
    styleUrls: [ './page.component.scss'],
    providers: []
})
export class AppPageComponent extends ResponsiveComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
    ResponsivePageComponent;

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        zone: NgZone)
    {
        super(zone);    
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {       
        this.IsSmallEnvironmentStream
            .subscribe
            (
                (isSmall: boolean) =>
                { 
                    if (isSmall)
                    { 
                        this.ResponsivePageComponent= AppPageSmallComponent;
                    }                   
                },
                (err) => { },
                () => {}
            );

        this.IsMediumEnvironmentStream
            .subscribe
            (
                (isMedium: boolean) =>
                { 
                    if (isMedium)
                    { 
                        this.ResponsivePageComponent = AppPageMediumComponent;
                    }                   
                },
                (err) => { },
                () => {}
            );

        this.IsLargeEnvironmentStream
            .subscribe
            (
                (isLarge: boolean) =>
                { 
                    if (isLarge)
                    { 
                        this.ResponsivePageComponent = AppPageLargeComponent;
                    }                   
                },
                (err) => { },
                () => {}
            );      
    }
}
```

Angular's documentation for [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) shows you can target optional list of projectable nodes to insert into the content (ng-content) placeholders.  I followed the examples from Angular's documentation and was able to inject text nodes into the different `ng-content` placeholders in my parent components and it works for my small/medium/large parent components.

How do I get the content from my routes to inject into these different placeholders?  It seems like I'm really close to getting this to work.  I can inject in essence static content into the palceholders, but I can not figure out how to inject the content generated by routes into the placeholders.

***UPDATE - 07/25/2017***

I created this [plunker demonstrating this scenario](https://plnkr.co/edit/hOwRX1Ml6gX0S8em6nd5?p=preview) (https://plnkr.co/edit/hOwRX1Ml6gX0S8em6nd5?p=preview).

In the plunker, `page-wrapper` component uses ngComponentOutlet to load small/medium/large component depending upon device width.  page-wrapper component is injecting static content into the placeholders in each small/medium/large component instead of injecting route content from page 1.

My objective is to have a page wrapper component to handle responsive needs like different navigation elements for small/medium/large responsive designs.

So, how can 'static' content be injected into dynamically loaded component's `ng-content` placeholders yet route generated content is not being injected into `ng-content` placeholders?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `router-outlet` is not defined in the HTML.

Comment: Hello! Can you say what exactly doesn't work? Route 3 doesn't transclude ng-content by selector? Would be great if you reduced the code in your plunker to minimal reproduction

Comment: @yurzui - thanks for the feedback. I've clarified the plunker.  The plunker just has 2 routes now.  Route 1 uses a 'responsive' parent component and its content does not get injected into parent's ng-content placeholders.  Route 2 uses a 'non-responsive' parent component and its content does get transcluded into its parent's ng-content placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You want to inject transcluded content in dynamic component instead `staticContent` It will only work if `ng-content` is located on direct child component. We need some workaround here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) You can define `ng-content` places in your PageWrapperComponent and transclude them to dynamic component

**page-wrapper.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="ResponsiveComponent; 
                                content: [[el1],[el2]]"></ng-container>
<div #el1>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div #el2>
  <ng-content select="[named-injection-point]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ang3epW43aQARAuPMzb3?p=preview)**

2) You can also use template reference variables(or custom directive) in parent component and `@ContentChild` in `PageWrapperComponent` to get transcluding sections.

**page-one.component.html**

```html
<page-wrapper>
    <section #mainPoint>
        <h2>Page One</h2>
    </section>
    <section #namedPoint>
        <h3>Page One Content:</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    </section>
</page-wrapper>
```

**page-wrapper.component.ts**

```typescript
@ContentChild('mainPoint') mainPoint;
@ContentChild('namedPoint') namedPoint;
```

**page-wrapper.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="ResponsiveComponent; 
        content: [[mainPoint.nativeElement],[namedPoint.nativeElement]]"></ng-container>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9EySFrYcMtWZ33qPES4Y?p=preview)**

Comment: The ngComponentOutlet directive uses an array of @ContentChild nativeElements to pass content to dynamically loaded components.  I have to put the array in a specific order to get the injected content into the correct ng-content.  Is there a way to guarantee what item in array gets injected into the correct ng-content in the dynamically loaded component?

Comment: @Tom Schreck You have to keep order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284026/creating-a-angular2-component-with-ng-content-dynamically/44289996#44289996 You should pass array in the same order as appropriate `ng-content` is appeared in template. Angular doesn't use `select` attribute in this case, only index

Comment: I tried to pass value using content, but i am not able to read content value in another component. I am using angular 5

Comment: @VenkateswaranR Can you setup a small repro?

Comment: I followed your 2nd example of plunker. But i didn't get content value

Comment: @VenkateswaranR Is it working as intended in my plunker?

Comment: I have created https://plnkr.co/edit/0t3VgzBEIRAUogYASjGO?p=preview, kindly check. Not able to get content value

Comment: @Venkateswaran Your example is completely different from my. I use wrapper but you pass content directly. https://plnkr.co/edit/lHFWI9KEHXPaJT4YKDkD?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui I understood, but my requirement is to pass content value from one component to another component using ng-container

Comment: @yurzui, is it possible to pass values from one component to another component using ngComponentOutlet in ng-container

Comment: @VenkateswaranR This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188151/angular-5-dynamic-component-creation-with-constructor/48188791#48188791

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're expecting? I've only tested the medium sized component BTW...

https://plnkr.co/edit/JgCQb4JVSHnHCueamerV?p=preview

I think it's because you're trying to use ng-content in a component that is not directly called from the component that has the content you want to inject. All I did was add an ng-content on the PageWrapperComponent, with it's own selector, then passed that on to the next component, with the selector that one is expecting.

PageWrapperComponent...

```
<ng-content select="[injected-content]" named-injection-point></ng-content>
```

Then in the PageOneComponent used the new selector the Wrapper is expecting

```
<section injected-content>
  <h3>Page One Content:</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
</section>
```

I can now see Page One Content below Jimmy and Fred when I click on the page 1 link.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I need to replace Jimmy and Fred with content from route, not place route data below Jimmy & Fred.  I was just using Jimmy and Fred as an example of content getting placed inside dynamic components.  I could not figure out how to get route data loaded instead.