# Angular: How to pass data in ngComponentOutlet through Injector

Tags: angular

I'm trying to dynamically create and show component and i need to pass some data into it, so that it knows what to show.

Here is my code:

html part:

```
<div class="basicContainer">
  <div class="projectsTreeContainer">


    <input type="text" id="searchWord" placeholder="Search through projects"/>

    <button (click)="loadAddProject()">Add new Project</button>

    <app-projects-tree (onLoadProjectDetails)="loadProjectDetails($event)"
                       (onLoadWpDetails)="loadWpDetails($event)"
                       (onSelectAndLoadJobDetails)="loadJobDetails($event)"></app-projects-tree>
  </div>

  <div class="infoContainer">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="details"></ng-container>
  </div>

</div>
```

Components:

```
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  details: Component;
  private showWp: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }


  loadProjectDetails(project: BasicProject): void {
     this.details = new ProjectComponent(project);
  }
```

and the component i want dynamically create and show:

```
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  project: Project;

  constructor(basicProject: BasicProject) {
    this.project = new Project();
    this.project.name = basicProject.name ;
  }
```

NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ProjectsComponent,
    ProjectComponent,
    ProjectsTreeComponent,
    TreeProjectComponent,
    TreeWpComponent,
    WpComponent,
    JobComponent,
    AddProjectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      AppRoutes.appRoutes,
      // {enableTracing: true} // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    ProjectsService,
    CanActivateAuthGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ProjectComponent, WpComponent, JobComponent, AddProjectComponent]
})
```

The error message:

> ProjectsComponent.html:15 ERROR Error: No component factory found for
>   [object Object].

How can i do the task?
Thanks.

Comment: You should pass type(`ProjectComponent`) not object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you open the code of `NgComponentOutlet` directive:

```typescript
@Directive({selector: '[ngComponentOutlet]'})
export class NgComponentOutlet implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ngComponentOutlet: Type<any>;
  @Input() ngComponentOutletInjector: Injector;
```

you can notice that it takes `ngComponentOutlet` input that should have type `Type<any>` but you're passing object to it.

Also we can see that this directive can take `Injector` as `@Input`. So lets leverage this knowledge to do your task.

For example we wrote template like:

```typescript
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component; injector: injector"></ng-container>
```

Now lets declare `component` and `injector` properties in component class:

```typescript
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  component: Type<any>;
  injector: Injector;

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.component = ProjectComponent; // note: we're passing type here
    this.injector = Injector.create([
      { provide: BasicProject, useValue: new Project('test name') }
    ], this.inj);
  }
}
```

and your `ProjectComponent` now uses angular DI mechanism to get data we passed to injector:

```typescript
export class ProjectComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor(project: BasicProject) {
    this.name = project.name;
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pshpuf?file=app%2Fproject.component.ts)**

Comment: This worked and your explanation has improved my understanding! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to yuzui's comment I managed to get something working

The full runnable code can be found on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pux5iz)

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Dynamic components in Angular 5';
  private injectors = {};

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {
  }

  get widgets() {
    return [
      {id: 1, widgetType:'child-component', settings: { showSecondLine: false} },
      {id: 2, widgetType:'child2-component', settings: { text: 'helloooooooooo'} },
      ];
  }
  
  getComponent(config: WidgetConfiguration) {
    switch (config.widgetType) {
      case 'child-component':
        return ChildComponent;
      case 'child2-component':
        return Child2Component;
    }
  }

   getInjector(config: WidgetConfiguration) {
    let inject = this.injectors[config.id];
    if (!inject) {
      inject = Injector.create([
        { provide: GeneralSettings, useValue: config.settings }
      ], this.inj);
      this.injectors[config.id] = inject;
    }

    return inject;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there change widgets to widgets = [], otherwise angular will keep calling the method in the ngFor loop. If you console log in the constructor for the component you find this is happening.