# Angular 6 - How to pass data in ngComponentOutlet

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new in angular 6.

I am using `ngComponentOutlet` in a for loop

I want to know how can I pass the data to my child component

My HTML

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="currentComponent"></ng-container>
</div>
```

My parent component who decides which component to chose

```js
export class MyParentComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private commonService: CommonService) { }

 dynamicComponents =  {
  'firstchild': {
   '1': FirstchildComponent
  }
 };

 currentComponent: any;
 items: any;

 ngOnInit() {
    // To get data from resolver
  const routeResult = this.route.snapshot.data.data.result;
  this.items = routeResult.items;
    
    // select child component at basis of route
  const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.params;
  this.currentComponent = this.dynamicComponents[routeParams.pageName][routeParams.templateType];
 }
}
```

My child component

```js
export class FirstchildComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() magazineData: any[];
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

So I want to pass item (single item of loop) to `FirstchildComponent` as a input

How can I do it?

I have checked with Injector

But as I am new, I don't really understand how injector works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 4+ assign @Input for ngComponentOutlet dynamically created component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522633/angular-4-assign-input-for-ngcomponentoutlet-dynamically-created-component)

Comment: have you looked at this? https://v6.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188151/angular-5-dynamic-component-creation-with-constructor/48188791#48188791 Instead of `BasicProject` you can use any token

Answer (score 10):

As you already pointed out, you need to use the Injector, which will provide all essential dependency data.

###MyParentComponent

```
@Component({...})
export class MyParentComponent  {

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {}

  createInjector(item){
    let injector = Injector.create([
      { provide: Item, useValue: item }
    ], this.inj);
    return injector;
  }
}
```

###Item Class
You will be having the class for `Item` if not then create new one with all properties  -

```
@Injectable()
export class Item{
   ...
}
```

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="currentComponent; injector:createInjector(item)"></ng-container>
</div>
```

###Dynamic Component

```
export class FirstchildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() magazineData: any[];
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(private item : Item) {  //<-- item content is here.
    }
}
```

> Note : The code has been written directly on stackoverflow editor so there could be typo and syntactical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: Note: you have to inject it in the constructor iso in the ngOnInit method, using an @Inject() annotation.

Answer (score 0):

ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver makes it easier than ngComponentOutlet when creating dynamic components.

### Dynamic Component

Template -

```
<div #dynamicComponent></div>

TS - 
@ViewChild('dynamicComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) podViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let componentFactory;
    let componentRef;
    try {
      componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(pod.component);
      componentRef = this.podViewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
      componentRef.instance.podInfo = this.podInfo;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: but I have a list of dynamicComponent: `@ViewChildren('dynamicComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) podViewContainerRefs;`. This gets me an array. I have, somehow, to pass data to that ng-container