# How to pass data to a component when opening a material popup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a component wrapper for popups (Angular Material MatDialog). In this component I am using ngComponentOutlet to dynamically display the children components.

popup-shell.component.html

```
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography popup-shell">
    <div class="popup-shell__container">
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data.component"></ng-container>
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

popup-shell.component.ts

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupShellComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) {}
```

When angular open popup, I pass information about which popup should be opened in the data field.

```
 constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
 
 openPopup() {
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupShellComponent, {
          data: { component: UserPopupComponent },
     });
 }
```

How can I pass data to UserPopupComponent when I open it in PopupShellComponent?

I know that I can use injector with ngComponentOutlet, but I couldn't make a working version.

Comment: You've already injected `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data`. If you `console.log(data)`, don't you see the data passed?

Comment: @eko I need to pass User1, User2 etc to UserComponent when opening it. Now it just static component

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53547609/5706293?

Answer (score -1):

Please read following blog it will be very helpful for you
[Using Mat Dialog](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/)