# Assign a variable from a ng-container

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML
`<ng-container *ngFor="let permission of perm.values" [(ngModel)]="permissions = permission">`

TS `permissions: [];`

Hi, I have this container in template and I have a permissions list in TS.
I wanted to fill that permissions field with the values I get from '*ngFor'.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the permission inside the ng-continer like that:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let permission of perm.values">
<p> {{permission}} </p>
</ng-container>
```

If you need more information take a look at [this.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/angular-ngfor-and-ngif-explained/)

Comment: i said i want it to assign the permission on the TS array

Comment: maybe do it with a += in the ngmodel or asign the perm.values directly in TS

Answer (score 0):

One approach is implementing a shared service as
[explained here](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/how-to-use-angular-services-to-share-data-between-components/);

Another approach is injecting data as you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541288/angular-6-how-to-pass-data-in-ngcomponentoutlet);

I came across a feature request for *ngComponentOutletInput and *ngComponentOutletOutput in addition of *ngComponentOutlet but it seems still to be WIP even if it has been argument of debate for years: in the mean while [this project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component) (ng-dynamic-component) looks well mantained and not a joke.

[This](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/advance-angular-dynamic-component-12e) approach (a custom directive) is also very interesting.

Answer (score -1):

your approach is off. in your component, you should fill your permissions array with the values:

```
this.permissions = [...this.perm.values];
```

then just iterate `permissions` in your `ngFor`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let permission of permissions" [(ngModel)]="permission">
```