# Angular structural directive: wrap the host element with some another component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have simplest Angular structural directive:

```js
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[hello]' })
export class HelloDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

I use it this way:

```
<div *hello>Hello Directive</div>
```

It shows me "Hello Directive" message as expected. Now I want to change the content by wrapping it with some another component:

```
<my-component>Hello Directive</my-component>
```

And I want the directive to do it for me. I know that I can use a Component paradigm and create `HelloComponent` instead of `HelloDirective` and use `ng-template` etc with the template defined by `template` or `templateUrl` property on the `@Component` decorator... But is there an approach that could be used with a Directive paradigm to achieve such a result?

Comment: Do you want to transclude directive's contents into component?

Comment: @yurzui Yes, and then pass the result into the initial template instead of directive's content. So that it could be interpreted as `<div *hello><my-component>Hello Directive</my-component></div>` at the end (instead of `<div *hello>Hello Directive</div>`).

Comment: Does `my-component` contain `ng-content`?

Comment: @yurzui It could be fully customized to provide proper behavior. No limitations on `my-component` implementation in this task.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create component dynamically and pass projectable nodes to it. So it could look like

```typescript
@Directive({ selector: '[hello]' })
export class HelloDirective implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  templateView: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;
  constructor(
      private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
      private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
      private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.templateView = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView({});
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
    this.viewContainer.createComponent(
      compFactory, null, this.viewContainer.injector, [this.templateView.rootNodes])
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.templateView) {
        this.templateView.detectChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

You have to add `MyComponent` to `entryComponents` array of your `@NgModule`

Complete example can be found on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhmyhe?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)**

See also

- [Creating a angular2 component with ng-content dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284026/creating-a-angular2-component-with-ng-content-dynamically)

Comment: If I use an nested component inside hello directive, it doesn't work. Do you have a sugesstion to fix that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-97ckey?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @MuratÇorlu Did you mean hello component didn't get input? That's because its view is not part of angular change detection tree. Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrtnmn?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Great, thanks. Another question is, now hello component in hello directive is initializing when directive is embedded the content, but not destroying when content is removed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3a4gn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html do you also have a suggestion to destroy hello component when we remove content from dom?

Comment: @yurzui I have had a dx-text-box from devextreme, and code was not working, after I fixed the issue I updated your answer (since many developers copy paste and they want it to work out of the box)