# Angular 5: How to embed a component into another

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

imagine, I have a generic table component with expandable rows and I need to inject another dynamic content (a dynamic SVG in this case) into this expandable rows from within a component, that uses the table.

***Example:***

**my-table.component.html**

```
// my-table-component

...

<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">

  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail; let i = index;">
    <ng-container>
      <div>

          <ng-content>here goes an SVG</ng-content>

      </div>
    </ng-container>

  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

...
```

**my-parent.component.html**

```
  <my-table *ngIf="tableData" [dataSource]="tableData [tableConfig]="tableConfig">

    <!-- this should go to ng-content in my-table with row specific data -->
    <my-svg [data]="my--data | async" [options]="my-options"> </my-svg>

  </my-table>
```

The problems here are,

- that `ng-content` is only for static contents, so that the `select` attribute can not hold a dynamic value.
- Only the last row contains the content, so that the dynamic SVG is only visible in the last row.

We have also tried ViewChild and templateRef and got no solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284026/creating-a-angular2-component-with-ng-content-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we found a solution using ngTemplateOutlet, and a ngIf condition:

***Solution:***

**my-table.component.html**

```
<ng-template #content><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
<div *ngIf="detail.element.expansionId == expandedElement">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Thanks @all