# Add child component to parent component and add parent to document

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-components

In an Angular 7 modal service I am creating a modal [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-jut4tt).

The modal is simply a DIV added to document as follows:

```
const modal = document.createElement('div');
modal.classList.add('modal');
modal.appendChild(this.element);

document.body.appendChild(this.modal);
```

The `modal` content (this.element) is a component created dynamically.

What I would like is `modal` to be also a Component added dynamically:

1. Create modal from a ModalComponent (I think similar to 2);
2. Create element component (DONE);
3. Add element component as child of modal component;
4. Add modal component to document.

Could someone help me with (3) and (4)? Not sure how to do it.

**Modal**

```
export class Modal {
  protected modal: any = null;
  close() {
    this.modal.close();
  }
}
```

**ModalService**

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, EmbeddedViewRef, Injectable, Injector, ComponentRef, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ModalService {

  private component: ComponentRef<any>;
  private element: any;
  private stage: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private application: ApplicationRef, private injector: Injector) { }

  open(component: any, data: any): void {

    if(this.element) 
      return;

    const injector: Injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([{ provide: 'modal', useValue: data }]);

    this.component = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component).create(injector);

    this.component.instance.modal = this;

    this.application.attachView(this.component.hostView);

    this.element = (this.component.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    const modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.classList.add('modal');
    modal.appendChild(this.element);

    document.body.appendChild(this.modal);

  }

  close(): void {

    this.application.detachView(this.component.hostView);
    this.stage.parentNode.removeChild(this.stage);
    this.component.destroy();
    this.element = null;

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please update your stackblitz link?

Comment: Done ... I deleted the link by mistake.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the ModalComponent in your example? I only see HelloComponent(which is element I suppose)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284026/creating-a-angular2-component-with-ng-content-dynamically

Comment: @yurzui I just added the Modal.component.ts, Modal.component.html and Modal.component.css. What I am looking for is ModalComponent to be used as parent of the, in the case, HelloComponent and added to the document. Instead of using document.createelement

Comment: @yurzui I checked that question and in fact I tried something of that but I wasn't able to make it work ... But to be honest I am not completely sure of the path to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to dynamically create that inner component  and then use `projectableNodes` parameter in `ComponentFactory.create` method to project it into your dynamically created `ModalComponent`.

The ModalComponent is supposed to have ng-content tag in its template:

```
<div class="stage">
  <div class="modal">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

**modal.service.ts**

```
open(component: Type<Modal>): void {
  if (this.modalRef)
    return;

  this.elementRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(component)
    .create(this.injector);
  this.appRef.attachView(this.elementRef.hostView);
  this.elementRef.instance.modal = this;

  this.modalRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent)
    .create(this.injector, [[this.elementRef.location.nativeElement]]);
                                         \/
                      here we're projecting inner component into modal

  this.appRef.attachView(this.modalRef.hostView);

  document.body.appendChild(this.modalRef.location.nativeElement);
}


close(): void {
  this.appRef.detachView(this.elementRef.hostView);
  this.elementRef.destroy();
  this.elementRef = null;

  this.appRef.detachView(this.modalRef.hostView);
  this.modalRef.destroy();
  this.modalRef = null;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-iqwkkg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal.service.ts)**